# How do you specify the solver in Pulp

Tags: python, pulp

I use the library Pulp to solve linear programming problems in python, I read that the solver can be specified (primal or dual simplex, interior point, ...), but I found nothing about how to do it. The only example I read is calling the solve() function with

`prob.solve(pulp.COIN_CMD(msg=1, options=['dualSimplex']))`

but it generates the following error: `PulpSolverError: Pulp: cannot execute cbc.exe cwd:`

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your pulp installation has issues with its cbc.exe.

Is it actually there and axecuteable?
Have you followed the installation instructions?

https://coin-or.github.io/pulp/main/installing_pulp_at_home.html

You could verify this like this:

```
>>> import pulp
>>> pulp.pulpTestAll()
```

**to your question**

your calling solve correctly, I think.
Fix the cbc.exe error at first :)

Comment: The solver is working when I let the function empty: prob.solve(), but I don't know what solver is actually used. I just updated Pulp to 2.0 with pip, and it seems that the pulp.pulpTestAll() is no longer available.